# Can't move image to folder, that is used by express static

Tags: express, go

I have "static" folder. This folder is used by express static. I created service (written in Go) which makes images smaller, so it can properly display on frontend. But when file is being moved to "static" folder it occures "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error.

(it worked great on linux, but on windows it shows me this error)

Let me know if any code is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not moving it with go script, using node (which is the process that uses static folder) instead.